# How to subclass or patch the query when user is being populated by AuthenticationMiddleware

Tags: python, django

I have extended the Django default AbstractUser by creating this Visitor model that has more information on user.

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='visitor')
```

By looking at the wonderful Django Debug Toolbar, I noticed that both the User model and this Visitor model cause a database query on every request. That go me thinking that it might worth while to put `.select_related("visitor")` in the query that gets the User model.

By following the rabbit hole starting from `AuthenticationMiddleware`, I was able to deduce that user model is fetched in `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.get_user()`. I manually edited the file in my environment to include the `.select_related("visitor")` and it worked like a charm.

Obviously editing package files in environment is not optimal. So the question now becomes: how would I proceed to subclass, patch or otherwise accomplish this in a clean manner?

Using Django 3.2.12 with Python 3.10 btw

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work quite simply, it seems.

First I subclassed the AbstractUser and made a custom Manager for it:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    objects = UserManager()
```

and then to override the `.get_queryset()` in it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related("visitor").all()
```

This has the exact desired outcome I was looking for. Is this the way to go?